# Configure OAuth creating DefaultConnection database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oauth, asp.net-membership

In my application (ASP.NET WebForms 4.5), I'm using custom membership provider and MSSQL database with custom membership scheme. When creating a new user I simply call

```
dc.Users.Add(newUser);
```

in `MembershipUser CreateUser` method inside the membership provider and then return a new MembershipUser instace constructed from received data. (`dc` is my DataContext)

Now, I added support for OAuth based on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/12/integrate-openauth-openid-with-your-existing-asp-net-application-using-universal-providers.aspx) tutorial. The problem is, that it stores newly created users' OAuth tokens into an automatically created database DefaultConnection, not into my own database. I don't like this behaviour. How to tell OAuth to store the tokens into my own database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting

```
OpenAuth.ConnectionString
```

in Global.asax right after registration on the name of my connectionString in web.config solved the problem.